# Change Savon's output when WSDL requires (complexType - sequence) containing multiple elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, soap, wsdl, savon

I'm trying to use Savon to access a SOAP API with a WSDL available.

In the WSDL, it defines a complexType as follows:

```
<s:complexType name="UserAdd">
  <s:sequence>
    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" name="user_location" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" name="number" type="s:string"/>
    <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" nillable="true" name="user_table" type="s:string"/>
  </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

I know the server is expecting request in this format:

```
<item>
  <key xsi:type="xsd:string">user_location</key>
  <value xsi:type="xsd:string">here</value>
</item>
<item>
  <key xsi:type="xsd:string">number</key>
  <value xsi:type="xsd:string">1234549789</value>
</item>
<item>
  <key xsi:type="xsd:string">user_table</key>
  <value xsi:type="xsd:string">there</value>
</item>
```

However, when I generate the query in Savon as follows:

```
hash_of_vars = {user_location: here, number: 1234549789, user_table: there}
response = @@call_client.call(:user_add, message: {data: hash_of_vars})
```

Savon instead generates XML that looks like this:

```
<data><user_location>here</user_location><number>1234549789</number><user_table>there</user_table></data>
```

The error being received from the server when this is being run is:

```
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

Is there a way to get Savon to conform to the WSDL and output the request in the format that the server expects to see, without creating a hash which explicitly defines all the item/key/value relationships?

Comment: The canonical question: Have you tried the interface using SoapUI? How does look the successful SOAP message? Work your way backward to Savon code that creates this message.

Comment: I haven't done it from SoapUI, but I have got a packet dump from a PHP application making this request, and it is successful.

Comment: I've just given in and built a nested array of hashes with the attributes added, it's working with that, now.